# How do I return specific array data from php?

Tags: php, arrays, curl, async-await, coinbase-api

I am using async/await to fetch a file (createCharge.php) that contains arrays with data inside when `<button>` is clicked on checkout.html

If I use `print_r` I can see all the results in the console such as the name, description, amount and even a new generated 'hosted_url'
that the customer will use to continue to their payment.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to fetch the hosted_url result into the checkout page and into the `<a href="">Pay now!</a>`.

This is what I have on my checkout.html...

```
<button id="btn">Pay with Crypto?</button>

<p id="pay"></p>

<script>
  btn.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {e.preventDefault();
  const response = await fetch('coinbasePHPtest/createCharge.php/');
  if (!response.ok) {
  const errorMessage = await response.text();
  console.error(response.status, response.statusText, errorMessage);
  alert('There was an error creating the charge.');
  return;
  }            
  const newurl = await response.text();
  console.log(newurl);
      
  pay.innerHTML = `<a href="${newurl}">Pay Now! - Coinbase</a>`;
  });
</script>
```

You can see I'm trying to bring the hosted_url into the `<a>` tag within the `<script>`.

And here is my createCharge.php that actually creates the hosted_url... (Example: https://commerce.coinbase.com/charges/xxxxx)

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/charges');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(
array (
'name' => 'My-Company',
'description' => 'Selected Product',
'local_price' => 
array (
'amount' => '147.00',
'currency' => 'GBP',
),
'pricing_type' => 'fixed_price',
'metadata' => 
array (
'customer_id' => 'id_1',
'customer_name' => 'Satoshi Nakamoto',
),
'redirect_url' => 'https://www.my-site.co.uk/Checkout/payment_successful.php',
'cancel_url' => 'https://www.my-site.co.uk/Checkout/payment_cancelled.php',
)
));

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'X-Cc-Api-Key: MY-API-KEY';
$headers[] = 'X-Cc-Version: 2018-03-22';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);


$response = json_decode($result, true);

return $response->data->hosted_url;

?>
```

I also tried..

```
pay.innerHTML = `<a href="${hosted_url}">Pay Now!</a>`

pay.innerHTML = `<a href="{hosted_url}">Pay Now!</a>`

pay.innerHTML = `<a href="${newurl->hosted_url}">Pay Now!</a>`

pay.innerHTML = `<a href="{.hosted_url}">Pay Now!</a>`
```

with no luck.

and...

```
btn.onclick = async() => {
const response = await fetch('coinbasePHPtest/charge.php/hosted_url');
const data = await response.json();

&

btn.onclick = async() => {
const resp = await fetch(`coinbasePHPtest/createCharge.php/${hosted_url}`);
const data = await resp.json();
```

**Solution:**

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$response = json_decode($result, true);

echo $response['data']['hosted_url'];
```

**This code within the createCharge.php worked for me! :)**

Comment: I've only messed with PHP for about 20 minutes but your `echo print_r echo` are after the return statement.  That's generally a bad thing, no?

Comment: @Travis Hi your correct yes but if I put it back the other way it just returns the same thing, all the data rather than just the hosted_url

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What keeps you from returning exactly what you want to return, instead of `<pre>`  and a dumped array?

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm just unsure on whether I should be fetching all data and then somehow selecting which data within the `<a>` tag `href` or whether I should just return the one piece of data (hosted_url). Also I'm unsure on whether the `<script>` needs to be `await response.json` or `.text` as its a link I wouldn't think it would matter

Comment: What does the console.log(data) logs?

Comment: @MadeInDreams Hi, it just shows `<empty string>`, If I use `print_r ($response)` I can see all array data including a newly generated url for the customer, theres just no way I can get the url to go into the `<a href="">`  on checkout.html

Comment: print_r? You mean that the PHP script is returning a response when you fetch the uri?

Are you aware that you are making an Ajax call?

Comment: @MadeInDreams Yes I get all data from the PHP file including the url that is needed, So I know this is all working but how do I echo out just the url? I'm completely new to using API's and I've managed to get it this far where I can create the charge and access the charge url through console, its just echoing it out that I can't understand

Comment: Unclear... in the front end you have a response that should contain everything.

response.data.  should be the data from PHP in an JSON format or object like. But you don't echo it out of there because your in the client browser when you read that so you have to handle it with JavaScript.

Comment: @MadeInDreams Hmm okay, do you know what kind of javascript I would need for this?

Comment: You have to preform Ajax call. This is want you want to search for.

Comment: what is your console.log(data) output?

Comment: @Travis I just get `<empty string>` but if I use `print_r` I receive all the array data inside console, so I can see its generating a new Charge and functioning correctly, the array data also goes into my "Pay Now" `<a>` tag but I can't specify which piece of data.

Comment: Sorry, I missed MadeInDreams asked the same. I think return isn't doing what you think it's doing. but again i've only looked at PHP long enough to know what it stands for. I think you want to simply output the json similar to the print_r is doing.maybe `echo $response` for the full json or `echo $response->data->hosted_url` or `echo $response[data][hosted_url]` or however PHP accesses the array data.

Comment: @Travis Yes this is exactly what I wanted to do, its so fussy on how it's formatted lmao, I tried the `echo $response` I get `<empty string>` I try the `echo $response->data->hosted_url` still `<empty string>` AND I tried `echo $response['data']['hosted_url']` previously and couldn't get it working BUT this time `echo $response['data']['hosted_url'];` is actually WORKING OMG after so long! Thankyou! I knew it was something simple but didn't realise it was THAT simple lmao, thanks again! I will add the solution below the question for other people to see :)

Comment: possible you had the echo after your return which stops processing so the echo didn't happen. glad its working. I'll create an answer so you can close it.

Comment: @Travis Yeah something like that hahah, Okay yeah that be awesome, hopefully this helps other people in future, Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to just output the data instead of using return. replace

```
return $response->data->hosted_url;
```

with

```
echo $response['data']['hosted_url'];
```